# How can I use a variable instead of a floating value for time.sleep()

Tags: python

I am writing a python script that needs to have a variable delay time, after looking around it seems like time.sleep() would be the best thing to use for creating pauses in the program, although I am not able to replace the floating value that time.sleep expects with a variable instead. Would there be any way to do this?

```
time.sleep(somevariable)
```

Comment: I dont understand, you can declare a variable with x= 10 then do time.sleep(x) and that does what you want

Comment: what output do you get when you try to use a variable? show us the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure that `somevariable` is a number not a string. You can convert with:

```
somevariable = "1.1"
somevariable = float(somevariable)
```

but if you can better to just make it a float:

```
somevariable = 1.1
time.sleep(somevariable)
```

Note: you obviously need to have the `time` module imported for any of this to work.

Comment: had been attempting to put a string in there (had been doing something along the lines of delay = "10"). Thanks for clarifying that

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

somevariable = .9
time.sleep(somevariable)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly declare the variable as a numeric data type such as an integer.

will not work:

```
    clock=input("How many seconds will you take to read?")
    time.sleep(clock)
```

will work:

```
    clock=int(input("How many seconds will you take to read?"))
    time.sleep(clock)
```